# disk storage of arrays etc

Tags: c#, file, multidimensional-array, disk

Does anyone have experience with storing data on disk? What I have is an in-memory modelling application that can do calculations etc. Basically the data is stored as lists of objects, that have nested key-value collections like Dictionary< int, Dictionary< int, T>>.

Right now I use SQL-Server as a persistance layer but I use very few features of it. So I'm thinking I could write/ read the data to disk myself to reduce dependencies and ease installation.

So I wrote a little routine that writes each array to disk in roughly this format, where the words "ObjId", "Type", "Valid" and "Count" are not actually in the file, they're the 1st, 2nd, 3rd an 4th int in the byte[], then come < int, T > pairs. The 52 comes from 4 * 4 + 3 * (4 + 8). (4 bytes for int, 8 for double)

```
Bytes: 52

ObjId: 123 
Valid: 234  
Type: double
Count: 3
    1 .23
    2 .34
    3 .45
```

In real life there's no indentation etc, they're all sequential bytes in a long stream.

This is fine, to write once. But when I want to write an extra value somewhere in the middle I have to rewrite the whole thing. Also I can't update a single value easily.

One alternative is to write each object to a separate file so I would only have to rewrite that. But but that seems quite inefficient because I get files that are 1kb, but 4kB on disk so I'd be wasting space there.

So what do I need to to do, to be able to incrementenally write to this file on disk? I know SqlServer has 'pages' where it writes data, is that the way to go?

Is there any library ready to go for this type of problem? Maybe some virtual file that will let me treat them as seperate byte[] but handles the storage as a single psysical file? Ideally compressed.. (pushing it, but who knows.. I've been surprised before :-)

Thanks in advance,

Gert-Jan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the overhead of an RDBMS, you could use a key-value database like Berkeley DB. There is a C# interface for it here:

[Berkeley DB for .NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libdb-dotnet/)

You can have one entry for each array, and just rewrite that when you need to. The rest of the database file will be unchanged so it's much faster than rewriting the whole file.

You can reuse the serialization logic you've already implemented when you write out an array. All you need to add is a unique key for each array.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I knew of BDB as a mySql engine but never considered it for this. I will look into it over the weekend. Having a way to just put my byte[] in there and get it back seems pretty pretty much what I was looking for. I would prefer pure C# with source but this should be mature technology enough to use as a black box.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to get around having either 1 file per object, or having to rewrite the whole list of objects when you make a change. You could use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). It is a single file embedded database that is very fast and efficient. This means your application doesn't have any external dependencies on the db.

If you are writing your data directly, you should read and write it in [binary format.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa904194%28VS.71%29.aspx) You will be storing your integers in one byte instead of their ASCII representation (1234 = 4 bytes, but is a 1 byte int).

This will speed the reading and writing to the file.

Some code from the article:

```
    Hashtable addresses = new Hashtable();
    addresses.Add("Jeff", "123 Main Street, Redmond, WA 98052");
    addresses.Add("Fred", "987 Pine Road, Phila., PA 19116");
    addresses.Add("Mary", "PO Box 112233, Palo Alto, CA 94301");

    // To serialize the hashtable and its key/value pairs,  
    // you must first open a stream for writing. 
    // In this case, use a file stream.
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("DataFile.dat", FileMode.Create);

    // Construct a BinaryFormatter and use it to serialize the data to the stream.
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    try 
    {
        formatter.Serialize(fs, addresses);
    }
    catch (SerializationException e) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to serialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
        throw;
    }
```

Comment: A minor caveat with the BinaryFormatter is that the generated files will not be version-tolerant with regard to either the application's assemblies or the .NET Framework.

Comment: @High Performance Mark - Yes you are right, I should have put 255 or something.

Comment: Hi, I've used the BinaryFormatter before but it injects quite some metadata about classes etc in between the actual data that I don't need and bloat the files consideratebly. Also it handles so changes to classes rather poorly so I didn;t consider it for this. Thanks, GJ

Answer (score 1):

There are a thousand and one ways of storing information on disk.  You've already had suggestions about databases.  You might also want to consider structured file formats such as [HDF5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) which has bindings for languages including C#.  One of HDF5's strengths is its support for storing n-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other suggestions made here you could try MongoDB with NORM as a great, friction-free (no database to configure, no object relational mapping to create) way to store data without the overhead / cost of SQL server.