# Best way to store large numerical multidimensional arrays

Tags: sql-server, multidimensional-array

I have a lot of large multidimensional multidimensional arrays whose values I need to access frequently. I need to store them and retrieve them from the disk.

The default way of storing data is a RDMS, but I can't help but feeling like it is awkward for this situation. One doesn't want to make a table with 4096 columns (at which point the 8K row size limit of SQL Server Express, my current RDMS, becomes a problem). The alternative of storing an array in a table like:

Column 1 is x coordinate

Column 2 is y coordinate

Column 3 is the actual value

is a LOT of performance overhead as a single column or row in the original data set (not a column or row of the database) may be spread all over the hard drive, but maybe that is the right way to do it.

What experience can you offer about the best way to persist large multidimensional numerical data. Initialization and shutdown performance issues that are below 10 seconds I am probably OK with. If it creeps into minutes to pull all the data into memory, or to write it all out, that is a problem.

My example is 2 dimensional, some of the arrays have more.

Comment: when you say multi-dimentional array do you mean 3-4 or 1000 dimentions? also is your array always the same number of dimentions or it can vary?

Comment: Just a thought... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102237/disk-storage-of-arrays-etc

Comment: @JiggsJedi Interesting thought. I will look over it.

Comment: @ZdravkoDanev Working in 1000 dimensional spaces is common, because it just means each row has 1000 entries. 1000 dimensional arrays are not common, as if each dimension was size 2 there would be 2^1000 entries, which is on the large side. :)

Comment: there are cases where in a large multi-dimentional array most of the cells have a zero (or other default value) and you don't really need to store them. in those cases the one-row-per-cell solution could work quite nice.

Comment: @ZdravkoDanev Very good point. I agree. So no, I am not dealing with sparse arrays.

Answer (score 1):

A possibility for storing your arrays - if you want to use SQL Server - is to store one array per database row in an XML field.  You should have the advantage that it should be relatively quick to store or extract the XML, and XML parsers operating in-memory should be faster than an on-disk array index/cell value lookup retrieval.